# Rails - enforcing a dichotomy using associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a Devise User model with the standard fields. A User can have EITHER a Profile, or a House, but not both.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  attr_accessible ..... :profile_type
  has_one :profile, :dependent => :destroy
  has_one :house, :dependent => :destroy

end
```

In this current state, a User can have both a profile and a state. Suppose doing: User.first.profile returns the profile. I can then do User.first.house, returning nil. That doesn't seem very nice - in fact it seems like I'm going to run into invalid data issues later on.

Edit: This is for a situation where people are either looking for a place to stay, or they have a place to stay. So I have two categories of user that a person can be. These two categories are very distinct (i.e. a person looking for a place to stay will have very different fields to a person who has a place to stay).

Is there anyway to enforce this "either" relationship? I am very new to Rails mind you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can a model "belongs_to" either/or more than one model?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1700800/can-a-model-belongs-to-either-or-more-than-one-model)

Comment: That question seems a bit different, but I'm not 100% sure

Answer (score 1):

You could handle this with a custom validation -

```
validate :has_either_profile_or_house_but_not_both

private

def has_either_profile_or_house_but_not_both
  if profile.present? && house.present?
    errors[:base] << "User can have either a profile or house, but not both."
  end
end
```

It's possible there's a cleaner way to do this via software design, but without knowing the problem you're solving, this is the best suggestion I have.

Comment: This might be a case for a polymorphic `belongs_to`. Take a look at [this](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#polymorphic-associations).

Comment: Okay. Thanks. I've edited the original question and added a bit more detail.

Comment: Yeah, that's why I said that... from what I'm reading, if it were me in your shoes, I would remodel so I could do this with a polymorphic `belongs_to`.

Comment: Thanks @x1a4, using the polymorphic association seems to have worked. I wish I could go user.profile though, rather then having to go profile.user.

Comment: if you set it up correctly, you should be able to do that. user belongs_to profile, and profile has_one user.